# Can't get a widget to appear over Houdini without resorting to WindowStaysOnTopHint

Tags: pyqt4

I'm launching a widget from a 3D application (Houdini) and the only way I can reliably get the widget to remain on top is to...

setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

...however, it then remains on top regardless. At times I can instead set the Qt.Window flag and get the desired behavior, ie the widget appears on top but can then be raised or lowered...but I cannot get this behavior consistently.

The widget is not a child of the Houdini application, It's running as a standalone; consequently, I don't expect raise() setActiveWindow(), etc to have an effect.

Thoughts?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since it is generally considered bad form to allow applications to force themselves to the foreground, you won't find any reliable way to do this in Qt. There are some OS specific methods though and you can find most of them on this site by searching for "[qt active foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=qt%20active%20foreground)".